# merge ActiveRecord::Relation with ActiveRecord::Associations

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, active-record-query

I have 2 models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :games

    def created_games
        Game.where(created_by: self.id)
    end
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

u = User.take
joined_games = u.games
created_games = u.created_games
```

the variable joined_games is a instance of ActiveRecord::Associations, and created_games is an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation.

Is there any way I can join joined_games and created_games together?

Comment: if user creates a `game` does it mean that this user "has" this game? Other words does it mean that `user.games` include created game?

Comment: no, actually there are 2 foreign keys in games table, :user_id and :created_by, they both points to User model, the difference is :user_id is for games this user join, and :created_by is for the games this user create. there might be overlapping, but basically they are 2 different sets

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a scope in User model

```
scope :joined_games, where(user_id: self.id, created_by: self.id)
```